# spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis AWS

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, spring-cloud-stream, spring-integration-aws

How can we have two AWS kinesis connections using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis?

1st connection: spring application and AWS kinesis stream in the same AWS account.

2nd connection: other AWS kinesis stream sitting in a different AWS account.

Is it possible to have two different connections from a spring application to two different kinesis streams in different AWS accounts?
If it is yes, How do we implement this?

Answer (score 0):

See [Connecting to Multiple Systems](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-systems).

> By default, binders share the application’s Spring Boot auto-configuration, so that one instance of each binder found on the classpath is created. If your application should connect to more than one broker of the same type, you can specify multiple binder configurations, each with different environment settings.

Comment: Thank you very much  Gary, Btw, this is for  the AWS kinesis multiple binders,How can I implement two AWS kinesis binders at the same time.

Comment: The type of the binder should make no difference; just use the technique described there to set up 2 binders with different environments.

Comment: Thank you . :) challenge here is  to have two different AWS connections (need to support two different AWS credential providers to access one kinesis to same account and other one for different account ) . Really appreciate your comment/help on this. Thank you again .... Sidath

Comment: You really can't do that just as is based on the Spring Boot auto-configuration: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.0.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-aws.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration. You need to consider to divide your project to several independent microservices.